# How to detect Chromium OS using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, navigator, chromium-os

I use Windows to develop my app and I use `navigator.platform` to detect the OS type.

I don't have a Chromium OS so I don't know what the value will be returned by the above script.

Can someone tell me what it returns on Chromium OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the userAgent you will get Chrome and then **CrOS**

For example:
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; // Then check if the UA is something like: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 0.12.433) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.77 Safari/534.30

Here is a post I've wrote about it in the past: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/how-to-detect-it-is-a-chromebook/

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86 64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/12.0.742.112 Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30` Once I had an print in my logs. I have no idea what OS is it or browser type can you give me a hint