# Anyone know what navigator.platform returns on Chrome OS?

Tags: javascript, browser, operating-system

I have code to detect operating system:

```
            var isPC = isWindows();
            function isWindows(){
                return navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1
            }

            var isMAC = isMac();
            function isMac(){
                return navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac') > -1
            }

            var isLINUX = isLinux();
            function isLinux(){
                return navigator.platform.indexOf('Linux') > -1
            }
```

but I don't know (can't find) the navigator.platform value for Chrome OS,
does anyone know?

Comment: CrOS according to the following article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385479/how-to-detect-chromium-os-using-javascript

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883965), it returns "Linux i686". But that post is not updated since 2015.

Comment: @user3051640 That post shows what `navigator.userAgent` (among others) contains. That's not necessarily what `navigator.platform` returns. You might be right, but that's not clear from that post.

Comment: so I guess a combination of navigator.platform = "Linux" and navigator.userAgent contains CrOS.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.platform` does not return a string that uniquely identifies ChromeOS.

Using the JavaScript console on Google Chrome in my Chromebook (HP Chromebook 11), `navigator.platform` returns:

`navigator.platform`
"Linux X86_64"

Instead use `navigator.userAgent`.

`navigator.userAgent` returns a substring "CrOS X86_64" that is unique to ChromeOS.  Sample return value from the JavaScript console on Google Chrome for my HP Chromebook 11 is below.

`navigator.userAgent`
"Mozilla/5.x (X11; CrOS X86_64 13904.97.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.167 Safari/537.36"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).